# What does 'x' do in curve/dnorm, and why does it work in my function?

Tags: r, function, statistics, curve, magrittr

I am making a function `Prop.Histogram()` that plots data as a histogram showing the proportions with a normal distribution curve added to it. Addition of the curve was difficult for me to achieve, but I succeeded (see code below)!

Note: I personally prefer to work with the pipe-operator `%>%` from the package magrittr in my codes. Though, as probably not everyone is familiar with this operator and/or this package (or they prefer not to use it), I'll also provide the same code without using magrittr below.

**Code using magrittr**

```
Prop.Histogram <- function(data,
   xlim_min, xlim_max, x_BreakSize,
   ylim_max, y_steps) {

# Load packages
library(magrittr)

# Make histogram of data without y-axis
hist(data, freq = FALSE, ylab = "Proportion",
   xlim = c(xlim_min, xlim_max), breaks = seq(from = xlim_min, to = xlim_max, by = x_BreakSize),
   ylim = c(0, ylim_max %>% divide_by(., x_BreakSize)), yaxt = "n")

# I divided ylim_max by x_BreakSize, as I want ylim_max to be equal to the max proportion shown on the y_axis (and not to the max density)

# Add y-axis that shows proportion and not density
axis(side = 2,
   at = seq(from = 0, to = ylim_max %>% divide_by(., x_BreakSize), by = y_steps %>% divide_by(., x_BreakSize)),
   labels = seq(from = 0, to = ylim_max, by = y_steps))

box()

# Add curve to histogram
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)), lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")

}
```

**Same code without using magrittr**

```
Prop.Histogram <- function(data,
   xlim_min, xlim_max, x_BreakSize,
   ylim_max, y_steps) {

# Load packages
library(magrittr)

# Make histogram of data without y-axis
hist(data, freq = FALSE, ylab = "Proportion",
   xlim = c(xlim_min, xlim_max), breaks = seq(from = xlim_min, to = xlim_max, by = x_BreakSize),
   ylim = c(0, ylim_max/x_BreakSize), yaxt = "n")

# I divided ylim_max by x_BreakSize, as I want ylim_max to be equal to the max proportion shown on the y_axis (and not to the max density)

# Add y-axis that shows proportion and not density
axis(side = 2,
   at = seq(from = 0, to = ylim_max/x_BreakSize, by = y_steps/x_BreakSize),
   labels = seq(from = 0, to = ylim_max, by = y_steps))

box()

# Add curve to histogram
curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)), lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")

}
```

This code does exactly what I want it to do: it plots the proportions and adds a normal distribution curve to the plot. Though, I do have difficulties understanding why addition of the curve actually works.

**Main question (1)**: I have to put `x` as the first argument in `dnorm()`, and even though I have not defined `x`, it works! So my first and main question is: what is `x`, what does it do, and why does it work in my function?

**Second question (2)**: My second question is whether it is possible (and, if so, how) to use magrittr pipe-operators (`%>%`) in the line of code that adds the curve to the plot. (Even if using operators is not the best way to do so in this case, I am still interested in the answer as I am eager to learn!)

---

First of all, for those who want to try out my code: here is some data that is representative of data that I want to plot:

```
data <- rnorm(724, mean = 84, sd = 33)
Prop.Histogram(data,
               xlim_min = -50, xlim_max = 200, x_BreakSize = 10,
               ylim_max = 0.15, y_step = 0.05)
```

---

**Main question (1)**: role of `x` in `dnorm()`/`curve()`

I started by using `data` instead of `x` as the first argument of `dnorm()`, but this didn't work as it resulted in the following error message:

```
   Error in curve(dnorm(data, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)), lwd = 5,  :
   'expr' must be a function, or a call or an expression containing 'x'
```

But then, when I take `dnorm(data, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data))` and run it individually (not as an argument of `curve()`, it gives me 724 values (of which I don't know what they meaning, but at least it's not an error message). Which is weird, since using `data` as the first argument when `dnorm()` is part of `curve` in my formula results in an error message as we saw previously.

Then, when I change `data` for `x` and run `dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data))` (again not as an argument of `curve()`), it gives me another error message:

```
   Error in dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)) :
   object 'x' not found
```

This I can understand, as I've not defined `x` anywhere in my code. But that rises the question: why do I not get this same error message when I run my (working) function.

In short, I observed that `x` must be the first argument in `dnorm()` when `dnorm()` is used as an argument in `curve()`, but `x` cannot be used as the first argument when `dnorm()` is used individually. Conclusion: I am lost.

Of course, when I am lost in R, I always look at the help page of R. The help page of `dnorm()` states that `x` is a vector of quantiles... that's it. I know those words individually, but have no idea what it means in my code (as I've not defined `x`, so what vector or what quantiles is the R help page talking about?).

---

**Second question (2)**: use of magrittr in code

I've tried to write the code `curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)), lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")` using magrittr, but it does not work. Here are some examples I've tried:

```
data %>% dnorm(x, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.)) %>% curve(., lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")
data %>% dnorm(x, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.)) %>% curve(lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")
dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)) %>% curve(., lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")
```

They all result in the same error message:

```
  Error in dnorm(x, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data)) : 
  object 'x' not found
```

I'd like to know if it's possible to use magrittr operators like `%>%` in this situation (even if it's not the best option).

---

PS. This is my first time posting, so please feel free to give feedback or ask me for more information if needed. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `curve()` function uses non-standard evaluation. `x` is just a placeholder in the expression that it will plot.  See `?curve` for details.

In fact, `x` doesn't need to be the first argument, it can appear anywhere in the expression.  But you would want it to be attached to the first argument of `dnorm`, so putting it first works well.  If you want to see the effect of the `sd` argument on the density at 0, you could use

```
curve(dnorm(0, sd = x))
```

When you do put it first, the dummy `x` that `curve()` is looking for will be bound to the first argument of `dnorm()`, which happens to also be named `x`, as you saw on the help page.  It is the location at which you want to calculate the density.

When you called `dnorm(data, mean = mean(data), sd = sd(data))` you were asking it to calculate the density of a normal distribution with mean `mean(data)` and standard deviation `sd(data)` at *each* of the locations in `data`.  That's why you got a long vector response.

For your second question:  `magrittr` passes the result of things on the left of the pipe into the function call on the right.  There are some complicated rules for where those results appear:

1. If you don't use `.` in the function call, the value is used as the first argument.
2. If you do use `.`, the argument appears there, but maybe also in the first place.  I forget the exact rules; see `?pipe` for details.

So to get what you want, you could do this:

```
data %>% {curve(dnorm(x, mean = mean(.), sd = sd(.), lwd = 5, add = TRUE, yaxt = "n")}
```

I had to use the curly brackets to get `magrittr` to handle the `.` properly.